# Cross browser support for Websockets in ActiveMQ

Tags: javascript, cors, activemq-classic, mqtt

It seems clear that Apollo has support for CORS in their websockets protocol, but I can find nothing comparable in ActiveMQ. In Apollo you can add the parameter "cors_origin" to the connector description, but I can find nothing comparable in ActiveMQ's documentation. I've tried the Apollo parameter but I'm still getting connection refused errors.

I'm attempting to use the Paho Mqtt javascript client to connect. The Go clients I've written work fine over both tcp and websockets, but I've had no luck getting the js client to work.

I'm pretty sure the problem is CORS. Any ideas on how to configure ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1):

My problem with the refused connections had nothing to do with CORS. It was an authentication problem with the ActiveMQ broker (my bug, now fixed).

However, it is interesting to node that ActiveMQ appears to completely ignore the websockets "Origin" header from the browser. In other words, it will accept connections from any host (including localhost). Apollo appears to behave differently with specific CORS configuration.

Comment: I'm sure the project would be happy to have contributions to improve the websocket support